# append data to shared preference not overwrite it

Tags: android, save, sharedpreferences

Is it possible to append the data I store using `SharedPreferences` rather than overwriting each entry?

```
public void onClick(View argument) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(argument==save)
    {
        SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("userInfo", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor spe=sp.edit();
    spe.putInt("ID",Integer.parseInt(enteredID.getText().toString()));
        spe.putString("name", enteredName.getText().toString());
        spe.putString("password",enteredPassWord.getText().toString());
        spe.putInt("age", Integer.parseInt(enteredAge.getText().toString()));

        spe.commit();
        }   

}
```

Comment: what does "append" mean?

Comment: write new data at the last of the old data, not to delete the old one and write the new instead of.

Comment: MODE_APPEND, check this link: http://androidopentutorials.com/android-sharedpreferences-tutorial-and-example/

Answer (score 0):

Get the last value you put inside the SharedPreferences and concat with the new one, for instance:

```
 String prevString = spe.getString ("name", "");
 spe.putString("name", prevString.concat(enteredName.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: so how can i retrieve data for specific username??

Comment: @blackbelt.. how can i append a Gson array that i am already saving in prefs ??

Comment: well, you should retrieve the JSONArray you have saved, modify it with the data you want to add and store it again. Check the JSONArray documentation in order to understand how you can modify it